# Removing trailing zeros in an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that doesn't print the trailing zeros in an array.
My array size is 23.  I am trying to start from the 23rd position in a for loop and end the for loop once a one is reached.  Then I would only print up to that position.  I have can't seem to get it right though.  Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

```
void removeTrailZero(int array[]) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 23; array[i] == 0; i--) {
        // printf("%d", i);
    }

    for (int x = 1; x < i + 1; x++) {
        printf("%d",array[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: _I have can't seem to get it right though_ And, what, exactly, is wrong? What are you expecting to receive as output? What are you getting instead? Please provide [mcve] as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
for (i = 22; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (array[i] != 0)
        break;
}
```

Then print your array between 0 and i (included)

Comment: For loop can be simplified to `for (i = 22; i >= 0 && array[i] == 0; --i);`

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your code looks like C, not C++. At least assuming the tag is correct and you really want to write C++ rather than C, I'd consider using some of the algorithms in the standard library to handle at least part of the job.

The standard library has an `std::find_if` to use for finding the value you care about. This works with iterators, not directly with the underlying storage. Since you want to start searching from the end, you can use a `reverse_iterator` to find the correct point:

```
auto last = std::find_if(std::crbegin(array), std::crend(array), 
    [](auto i) { return i != 0; });
```

When we print out the data, we want to iterate *forward* through the array from the beginning to that point--but that's a reverse_iterator, so we need to call its `base()` to get a forward iterator, and give that as the end of the range we want to print:

```
std::copy(std::cbegin(array), last.base(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: Good solution, but only compile with `C++14`.

Comment: @chema989: quite true (but if you needed to port to C++11, it would be pretty trivial).

Answer (score 0):

If You compile with C++14 `-std=c++14` you can use the answer's @JerryCoffin:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

template <std::size_t SIZE>
void removeTrailZero(const std::array<int, SIZE>& array) {
    auto last = std::find_if(std::crbegin(array), std::crend(array),
        [](auto i) { return i != 0; });
    std::copy(std::cbegin(array), last.base(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 23> array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    removeTrailZero(array1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::array<int, 15> array2 = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    removeTrailZero(array2);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
❯❯❯ g++ -std=c++14 ../test.cc -o test && ./test
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 0 0 4 5 6
```

For compiling with C++11 `-std=c++11` you can use:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

template <std::size_t SIZE>
void removeTrailZero(const std::array<int, SIZE>& array) {
    auto last = std::find_if(array.crbegin(), array.crend(),
        [](int i) { return i != 0; });
    std::copy(array.cbegin(), last.base(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 23> array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    removeTrailZero(array1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::array<int, 15> array2 = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    removeTrailZero(array2);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
❯❯❯ g++ -std=c++11 ../test.cc -o test && ./test
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 0 0 4 5 6
```

For older version of C++11, you can use:

```
#include <iostream>

void removeTrailZero(int array[]) {
    int i = 22;
    for (; i >= 0 && array[i] == 0; --i);
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
        std::cout << array[j] << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    removeTrailZero(array);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    int array2[] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    removeTrailZero(array2);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
❯❯❯ g++ ../test.cc -o test && ./test
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 0 0 4 5 6
```

> Note: For C++11 and C++14, `removeTrailZero` is a template function and can receive diferent sizes of `std::array`. For older version of C++11 `removeTrailZero`is design for receive a `int[23]`.